# SugarCRM - Will workflow works during importing of files?

Tags: sugarcrm

I would like to ask if there is a relationship between the Workflow and Importing of Files.

For example, the execution of workflow occurs when a record is saved, and it applies to updated records. And the action is to update a certain field on the target module if a specific field is changed. Say for example, Field A is updated to YES if field B is changed.

So it works well, when I manually saved the module after updating the field B.

How about during importing? Will the workflow would still matter? Provided that all conditions were successfully met.

I hope you could help me on this. I need to update our TS if there's a need for hard coding to support this.

Actually I have already posted this on the sugar forums. :D

Thanks so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Workflows are triggered with a before_save logic hook.

Logic hooks are triggered anytime the save() function is called

Creating records via the import process calls the the save() function.

So, yes, importing records will trigger your workflows.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is yes. There is no long answer.

Sugar uses the SugarBean class to save records, and it handles workflow. So if you save through Sugar, import, or use web services they all use SugarBean so therefore handle workflow.